# Removing the value from a multi value list

Tags: c#, list

Alright I have setup the following to start data within the list:

```
public class OnlineList
{
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int PID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I am using the following to see if a value exists:

```
bool nameCheck = OnlineList.Any(cus => cus.Username == username);
if (nameCheck)
{
}
```

My question is how do I remove a value from the list where username = username ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using **[Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx)** method?

> Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the `List<T>`.

```
var match= OnlineList.Single (cus => cus.Username == nameToRemove);
OnlineList.Remove(match);
```

If you need remove all usernames which do you want to delete which username, you might want to use **[RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)** method same way.

Comment: How would I grab the value of PID where username is = x ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `RemoveAll`

```
OnlineList.RemoveAll(x=>x.Username == username);
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use `RemoveAll`

```
OnlineList.RemoveAll (cus => cus.Username == username); // remove by condition
```

(2) Using `LINQ`, you can use `Except`

```
lst = OnlineList.Except(OnlineList.Where(cus => cus.Username == username)).ToList();
```